# Quando, como e porque a língua portuguesa foi dividida?

Tags: diferenças, história

Historicamente o Brasil foi colonizado por pessoas vindas de Portugal, porém a pronúncia e a escrita no Brasil e em Portugal são muito diferentes. Por que houve essa separação? Em que momento o Brasil passou a adotar uma forma distinta da língua portuguesa e como esse fato ocorreu?

Answer (score 12):

Eu não sei dar uma descrição exata da diferenciação dos dois dialetos, mas é importante ressaltar que não se trata de um fenômeno isolado, mas sim bem comum. Diferenças similares ocorreram em outras colônias europeias. O inglês dos Estados Unidos difere consideravelmente do europeu, assim como o castelhano falado na América é bem diferente do europeu, o francês do Quebec é bem diferente do europeu, etc. Por exemplo, ao lançarem o Harry Potter nos EUA, a editora aparentemente resolveu "traduzir" o livro do dialeto europeu para o americano, mesmo se tratando da mesma língua. Da mesma forma, alguns filmes que vêm do Quebec para a Europa são legendados, pois o francês de lá é às vezes difícil de entender para um europeu.

Vale lembrar também que não foi o português brasileiro que se tornou uma forma distinta da língua portuguesa, mas sim os dois dialetos que evoluíram independentemente a partir de uma mesma origem. Uma prova disso é que diversas construções no português brasileiro são arcaísmos do ponto de vista da variante europeia. Por exemplo, o uso do gerúndio no Brasil em construções como "eu estou comendo" é um reflexo do português falado no <s>século XV</s> século XVI, tanto no Brasil como em Portugal; foi o dialeto europeu que passou a usar a forma "estou a comer". Reciprocamente, o português europeu tende a usar muito mais as conjugações da segunda pessoa do singular (ou seja, aquelas ligadas ao "tu", como "comes" ou "amas"), enquanto que o Brasil passou a usar as formas da terceira do singular (ou seja, aquelas ligadas ao "você", como "come" ou "ama") de maneira muito mais generalizada. Mais uma vez, isso não se trata de um fenômeno restrito ao português, e podemos encontrar análogos noutras línguas como o francês e o inglês.

Comment: Gostei. Também no sotaque, foram, ao que parece, os portugueses, mais que os brasileiros, que se afastaram do Português quinhentista. Se calhar queres dizer século XVI.

Comment: @Jacinto, de fato!

Comment: Muito bom.  Pouco ficou a acrescentar.

Comment: Só acrescentando: O mesmo tipo de evolução ocorre dentro do próprio país, em escala um pouco menor. Mas sabemos que existem inúmeras variações em expressões, significados, pronúncia (até do próprio alfabeto) entre regiões do Brasil. Imagino que em Portugal também (em menor escala, pois o país é bem menor).